# Select from a list of background-colors and apply a different one to each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of articles (each "post/article" is contained in an `<article>` element).

I would like to randomize the background-color of each individual article, but restrict it to only a set list of colors (my palette).

*(Bonus: Is there any way to have it not repeat usage of a color until all the other colors in the list have been used?)*

List of colors that I would like to restrict it to:

```
#113F8C
#01A4A4
#00A1CB
#61AE24
#D0D102
#32742C
#D70060
#E54028
#F18D05
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E5J7a/1/) to test on which has everything included except for the meat of the jQuery function.

---

### Update: CSS-Only Solution

I came up with a good solution using only **CSS**! If I remove the need for any "randomness", I can simply use the css "nth-child" selector to achieve the task.

#### What this means:

- The order of the colors will always be the same each time the page is viewed (unless I manually change them, of course.)
- Colors will not repeat twice in a row.
- There is no "randomness" involved.
- I can add as many colors as I want to my palette. All I have to do is change the "`#`" in `:nth-child(#n+x)` to the total number of colors.

#### **The result:** http://jsfiddle.net/E5J7a/19/

```
article:nth-child(9n+1) {background-color: #113F8C;}
article:nth-child(9n+2) {background-color: #01A4A4;}
article:nth-child(9n+3) {background-color: #00A1CB;}
article:nth-child(9n+4) {background-color: #61AE24;}
article:nth-child(9n+5) {background-color: #D0D102;}
article:nth-child(9n+6) {background-color: #32742C;}
article:nth-child(9n+7) {background-color: #D70060;}
article:nth-child(9n+8) {background-color: #E54028;}
article:nth-child(9n+9) {background-color: #F18D05;}
```

Comment: Honestly, you haven't tried anything.. it is like you are assigning us some task.. this can be done easily if you know how to use arrays.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "do it and give me".

Comment: @Mr_Green I've spent a couple hours trying to figure this out by myself. I'm not the most familiar with javascript, especially not arrays. Also I will reword the question to be less "do it and give me".

Comment: @HarleyCreative: you can place your solution as an answer :)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I will as soon as I have permissions to. Since I'm new I have to wait a certain number of hours before I can answer my own post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code .First it creates an array .Then it will remove colors from array when they are used:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E5J7a/8/)

```
var colorArr = new Array('#113F8C','#01A4A4','#00A1CB','#61AE24','#D0D102','#32742C','#D70060','#E54028','#F18D05');

$("article").each(function() {
    var randomColor = colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArr.length)];
    var tg = colorArr.indexOf(randomColor); 
    colorArr.splice(tg, 1);
    $(this).css({'background-color':randomColor});
});
```

The above fiddle only colors number of articles equal to number of colors in array.If you want to reuse the same colors again and again use the below fiddle:

### [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/E5J7a/10/)

```
var colorArr = new Array('#113F8C','#01A4A4','#00A1CB','#61AE24','#D0D102','#32742C','#D70060','#E54028','#F18D05');

$("article").each(function() {
    var randomColor = colorArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorArr.length)];
    var tg = colorArr.indexOf(randomColor); 
    colorArr.splice(tg, 1);
    if(colorArr.length==0)
    {
        colorArr = new Array('#113F8C','#01A4A4','#00A1CB','#61AE24','#D0D102','#32742C','#D70060','#E54028','#F18D05');
    }
    $(this).css({'background-color':randomColor});
});
```

Comment: The second example is awesome! Learned a ton about ways to use arrays from this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Following is just randomize code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var color = ['#113F8C','#01A4A4','#00A1CB','#61AE24','#D0D102','#32742C','#D70060','#E54028','#F18D05'];
    $("article").each(function() {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length);
        $(this).css('background-color',color[random]);  
    });
});
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/E5J7a/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var color =['#113F8C','#01A4A4','#00A1CB','#61AE24','#D0D102','#32742C','#D70060','#E54028','#F18D05'];
    $("article").each(function() {
        if(color.length === 0) {
            color =['#113F8C','#01A4A4','#00A1CB','#61AE24','#D0D102','#32742C','#D70060','#E54028','#F18D05'];
        }
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*color.length);
        $(this).css('background-color', color.shift(random));  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) {

    var colors = ["#113F8C", "#01A4A4", "#00A1CB", "#61AE24", "#D0D102", "#32742C", "#D70060", "#E54028", "#F18D05"],
        colorsUsed = {}, $divsToColor = $('.post');

    $divsToColor.each(function () {

        var $div = $(this),
            randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

        $div.css('backgroundColor', randomColor);
        if (colorsUsed[randomColor]) {
            colorsUsed[randomColor]++;
        } else {
            colorsUsed[randomColor] = 1;
        }

    });

})(jQuery);
```

See the demo here.. http://jsfiddle.net/E5J7a/11/

Comment: This is great! Nice work! Now is there any way to achieve the "bonus" part of my question? Or at least make it so that it doesn't repeat the same one twice in a row?

Comment: Hi @HarleyCreative great to know it helped you.

Comment: @HarleyCreative Ok let me try that jQuery part.

Answer (score 0):

this is not random but will give you all color and none of them repeating itself until all colors are used once

```
var counter=0;
$("article").each(function(i) {
var arr=["#113F8C","#01A4A4","#00A1CB","#61AE24","#D0D102","#32742C","#D70060","#E54028","#F18D05"];
    $(this).css("background",arr[counter++]);
    if(i==arr.length-1)
        counter = 0;
});
```